# Attempted import error: 'Switch' is not exported from 'react-router'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a project in order to monitor employees and I have a side bar, and this side bar contains one element, and when clicking on this element, it should take me to the content of that element.

And in order to take me to the content of the element, I used "Switch", but it did not accept it, and this I had an error:

```
      import error: 'Switch' is not exported from 'react-router'.
```

Knowing that I use React with TypeScript.

How can I solve the problem?

```
const drawerWidth = 300;

interface Props {
    className?: string
    link?: string | null // because the InferProps props allows alows null value
    onClick?: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => void
    window?: () => Window;
}


export default function ResponsiveDrawer(props: Props) {
    const {window , link} = props;
    const classes = useStyles();
    const theme = useTheme();
    const [mobileOpen, setMobileOpen] = React.useState(false);

    const handleDrawerToggle = () => {
        setMobileOpen(!mobileOpen);
    };

    const drawer = (
        <div style={{/*boxShadow: 'inset 0 0 10px'*/  boxShadow: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 1.95px 25px 
           2.6px'}}>
            <div className={classes.toolbar}/>
            <Button startIcon={<ArrowBackIosIcon/>}
                    style={{marginLeft: '3.5rem', borderRadius: 24, background: '#7b68ee', fontSize: 
             '1.4rem'}}
                    variant="contained">
                Back
            </Button>
            <Box sx={{p: 5}}>

                <h1 style={{paddingLeft: '1rem', fontSize: '2rem', color: '#d5d6d7'}}>Settings</h1>
                {/*workspace Name*/}
                <Typography style={{
                    paddingLeft: '1rem',
                    fontSize: '1.6rem',
                    color: '#7b68ee',
                    fontWeight: 700
                }}>Slark</Typography>
                <List>
                    {/*<Link to='/setting/sidebar/settings' style={{textDecoration: 'none', color: 
               'red'}}>*/}
                        <ListItem button component={forwardRef((props: NavLinkProps, ref: any) => 
                <NavLink exact {...props} innerRef={ref} />)}
                                  to='/setting/sidebar/settings'>
                            <ListItemText
                                style={{color: '#d5d6d7'}}
                                classes={{
                                  primary: classes.fontSize,
                                }} primary="Settings"/>
                        </ListItem>
                        
                </List>
               
            </Box>
        </div>
    );

    const container = window !== undefined ? () => window().document.body : undefined;

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <CssBaseline/>

            <nav className={classes.drawer} aria-label="mailbox folders">
                <Hidden smUp implementation="css">
                    <Drawer
                        container={container}
                        variant="temporary"
                        // anchor={theme.direction === 'rtl' ? 'right' : 'left'}
                        open={mobileOpen}
                        onClose={handleDrawerToggle}
                        classes={{
                            paper: classes.drawerPaper,
                        }}
                        ModalProps={{
                            keepMounted: true, // Better open performance on mobile.
                        }}
                    >
                        {drawer}
                    </Drawer>
                </Hidden>
                <Hidden xsDown implementation="css">
                    <Drawer
                        classes={{
                            paper: classes.drawerPaper,
                        }}
                        variant="permanent"
                        open
                    >
                        {drawer}
                    </Drawer>
                </Hidden>
            </nav>
           <main className={classes.content}>

                <Container maxWidth="lg">

                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/setting/sidebar/my-settings" exact component={SettingsPage} />
                    </Switch>

                </Container>
            </main>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Where's your `import` statement?  And `Switch` is exported from `react-router-dom` not `react-router`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package you need is **`react-router-dom`**:

### Install the package(s)

`npm install react-router-dom`

Since you are using TypeScript, also install the type definitions:

`npm install @types/react-router-dom`

### Import

```
import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'; // for example
```

Comment: problme still found.

Comment: Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-router-dom'

Comment: Have you installed the packages? `npm install react-router-dom`

Comment: yes, but the problem still found, And I got a second problem and it is:
Attempted import error: 'Navigate' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.

Comment: yes,
npm install react-router-dom and npm install @types/react-router-dom

Comment: And are you still getting can't resolve 'react-router-dom'

Comment: Not resolved and another problem appeared, namely:Attempted import error: 'Navigate' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.       Although this was not a problem previously

Comment: Are you trying to import a Navigate? I think you are trying to use another component

Comment: Could you take a look at your imports?

Answer (score 6):

`<Switch>` function was avaliable on react-router-dom till version 5.

On react-router-dom version 6, it was replaced by `<Routes>`.

About the missing Navigate(), the function is useNavigate() and is present on react-router-dom version 6.

Also, to clarify, react-router-dom has all functionalities that react-router have. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router

Answer (score 2):

First install `react-router-dom`   use the older version

```
npm install react-router-dom@5.2.0
```

Please try to `import react-router-dom` to your code and implement `switch`, `link` and `route`

It works for me it will work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

For `react-router-dom@6.3.0`, replace `Switch` with `Routes` and then `component` with `element`.

```
import { Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom";

<Routes>
    <Route path="/home" element={<Home/>} />
</Routes>
```